# How should I transfer a domain object's properties to its model counterpart?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

We currently use extension methods to provide this functionality, but I can't help but feel there's a much cleaner solution. I played around with AutoMapper, but I wasn't able to quite see how it solved the issue in complex cases. For a simple 1:1 it works, but if any fiddling of the data is required -- it seems to be a let down.

So, I've got something like:

```
public static class ProvisioningExtensions
{
    // Convert ProvisioningServicesProxy.Provisioning to ProvisioningDetailsModel.
    public static ProvisioningDetailsModel ToProvisioningDetailsModel(this Provisioning provisioning)
    {
        var provisioningDetailsModel = new ProvisioningDetailsModel
        {
            ID = provisioning.ID,
            TaskDeviceID = provisioning.TaskDevice.ID,
            ServiceGroupID = provisioning.ServiceGroup.ID,
            ServiceID = provisioning.Service.ID,
            PatchSchedules = provisioning.PatchSchedules.Select(ps => ps.ToPatchScheduleDetailsModel()).ToList()
        };

        return provisioningDetailsModel;
    }

    // Convert ProvisioningDetailsModel to ProvisioningServicesProxy.PatchSchedule.
    public static Provisioning ToProvisioning(this ProvisioningDetailsModel provisioningDetailsModel)
    {
        WorkflowManager workflowManager = new WorkflowManager();
        ProvisioningManager provisioningManager = new ProvisioningManager();

        TaskDevice taskDevice = workflowManager.GetTaskDeviceByID(provisioningDetailsModel.TaskDeviceID);
        Service service = provisioningManager.GetServiceByID(provisioningDetailsModel.ServiceID);
        ServiceGroup serviceGroup = provisioningManager.GetServiceGroupByID(provisioningDetailsModel.ServiceGroupID);

        var provisioning = new Provisioning
        {
            ID = provisioningDetailsModel.ID,
            TaskDevice = taskDevice,
            ServiceGroup = serviceGroup,
            Service = service,
            PatchSchedules = provisioningDetailsModel.PatchSchedules.Select(ps => ps.ToPatchSchedule()).ToArray()
        };

        return provisioning;
    }
}
```

ProvisioningDetailsModel is a class which just contains the model's properties. Nothing special.

I thought about decorating the Provisioning domain object such that it could be used in place of the model, but decided against it. What if I wanted to represent the Provisioning data in two different manners -- this would be impossible if I use the domain object itself as my model.

What other options should I be considering? Extension methods would be my last choice -- especially when I have to do relatively heavy work inside of ToProvisioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AutoMapper you can create type custom converters. This is done by implementing the ITypeConverter<> interface.

```
   public class CreateMomentoCommandToMomentoConverter : ITypeConverter<CreateMomentoCommand, Momento>
    {
        public Momento Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var source = (CreateMomentoCommand) context.SourceValue;
            var momento = new Momento {Username = source.Username};

            return momento;
        }
    }
```

Intialize the customer type converter with AutoMapper

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the aut do mapper.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureAutoMapper()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(c=> c.CreateMap<CreateMomentoCommand, Momento>().ConvertUsing(new CreateMomentoCommandToMomentoConverter()));
    }
```

And lastly map it.

```
Mapper.Map<CreateMomentoCommand, Momento>(command);
```